# Styling Actionbar causes the tabs to disappear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I tried to style my actionbar and tabs for my application but everytime I tried to style it, actionbar tabs disappeared

```
<resources>
<style name="STheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabView</item>
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/MyDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@color/orange</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBarTabView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
    <item name="showDividers">middle</item>
    <item name="measureWithLargestChild">true</item>
</style>
```

When I remove this line(actionbar style), tabs showed up:

```
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
```

Any one have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using AppCompact style in parent style than how can you use Holo style in child styles?
Update style parents like:

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
<style name="MyActionBarTabText" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
<style name="MyActionBarTabView" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
```

Also see this very useful page to cusomize actionbar : [ActionbarStyleGenerator](http://www.actionbarstylegenerator.com/)

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You are using support library `Theme.AppCompat`, so your custom styles `parent` should be like this:

```
<style name="MyActionBar"  
               parent="@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
     <item name="background">@color/orange</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabText"
               parent="@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
     <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
     <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBarTabView"
              parent="@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
     <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
     <item name="showDividers">middle</item>
     <item name="measureWithLargestChild">true</item>
</style>
```

[**UPDATE**]

For above styles, need change your `STheme` to be:

```
<style name="STheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
```

If you really want to use `style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` for `STheme` then accordingly have to change custom style parent:

```
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I tried it but I got error "Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar'."